# ASP.NET Web API Help Page documentation with Doxygen. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, doxygen, api-doc

[image]

Is it possible to generate this type of API documentation with Doxygen. If so how?

I do have all my controllers XML commented.

Answer (score 1):

HelpPage, by default, uses `XmlDocumentationProvider`(which depends on the default .net generated documentation) which implements `System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider`...You can create a custom IDocumentationProvider and where you can read the documentation generated by Doxygen...After creating this custom provider, you can replace the default one in `HelpPageConfig.cs`...

Comment: Will I be also able to  match the view/UI  generated and how the HelpPage looks?

Comment: yes, you would be able to...the interface that i mentioned only provides 'text' and so there would be no UI changes..